# Javascript - how do I add dynamic buttons to this slideshow?

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a slideshow with 4 divs that cycle around automatically. What I have works for this.
The thing I'm having diffucluty create is a few buttons at the bottoms where if your click on button three for example, it jumps to div 3 and the automatic sliding jumps there. Here is my code so far...

```
<div id="slides">
  <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
</div>

<div id="btns">
    <a></a> <a></a> <a></a> <a></a>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function slideshow(){

    var slides = document.getElementById('slides').children;
    var btns = document.getElementById('btns').children;
    var i = 0;

    slides[i].style.opacity= '1';
    btns[i].style.opacity= '1';
    slides[i].style.zIndex= '999';

    function timer(){
            i = (i + 1);    
            var len = slides.length;
            var previousSlides = slides[ (i+len-1) % len ];
            var previousBtns = btns[ (i+len-1) % len ];

            if (i % slides.length == 0) {
            i = 0;
            }

            slides[i].style.opacity= '1';
            slides[i].style.zIndex= '999';
            previousSlides.style.opacity= '0';
            previousSlides.style.zIndex= '1';   
            btns[i].style.opacity= '1';
            previousBtns.style.opacity= '0.5';
        }       
        setInterval(timer, 4000);

}());
```

This works so far, but again I have no idea how to go about making the buttons function, wherein if you click on btn[i] it jump to slides[i]. I thought something along the lines of this would do the trick but it's not working.

```
btns[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
    i = 1;
});
```

Comment: Also, totally unrelated to the main problem, but can someone explain this line from the code for me...  (i+len-1) % len ... I copied it from somewhere online, so it returns the previous element while looping around the array. Which works perfectly, but I don't really understand how...

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this hope this is what you want

```
for( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
     //do your stuff here
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
for( var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('test');
  });
}
(function slideshow(){

    var slides = document.getElementById('slides').children;
    var btns = document.getElementById('btns').children;
    var i = 0;

    slides[i].style.opacity= '1';
    btns[i].style.opacity= '1';
    slides[i].style.zIndex= '999';

    function timer(){
            i = (i + 1);    
            var len = slides.length;
            var previousSlides = slides[ (i+len-1) % len ];
            var previousBtns = btns[ (i+len-1) % len ];

            if (i % slides.length == 0) {
            i = 0;
            }

slides[i].style.opacity= '1';
            slides[i].style.zIndex= '999';  
            btns[i].style.opacity= '1';
            previousSlides.style.opacity= '0';
            previousSlides.style.zIndex= '1';   
           
            previousBtns.style.opacity= '0.5';
        }       
        setInterval(timer, 4000);

}());

function testButton(value){

if(value == 1){
alert('Slide'+value);
}
}

</script>
```

```html
    <div id="slides">
  <div>Slide 1</div> <div>Slide 2</div> <div>Slide 3</div> <div>Slide 4</div>
</div>
<div id="btns">
   <button type="button" onClick ="testButton(1);">Click Me1</button>
<button type="button" onClick ="testButton(2);">Click Me2</button>
<button type="button" onClick ="testButton(3);">Click Me3</button>

<button type="button" onClick ="testButton(4);">Click Me4</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hope this will answer your problem